# Digging into Oauth2.0 authorization code

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0

In the code below:
https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI/blob/master/IOSLinkedInAPI/LIALinkedInAuthorizationViewController.m

On lines 108-109, the author checks to see if the state parameter returned after the Oauth2.0 authentication is the same as the one passed in. Is that necessary? How would the state parameter change or be compromised in a webview?

Comment: Is this regarding Oauth2.0 in general or for linked in?

Comment: oauth2.0 in mobile apps. Is it necessary to check for state if you are implementing oauth2.0 via webview?

Answer (score 0):

RECOMMENDED.  An opaque value used by the client to maintain
state between the request and callback.  The authorization
server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
cross-site request forgery as described in Section 10.12.

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

However that said I do not think it is absolutely necessary as it would be a stretch for someone to try and do cross-site forgery due to the SSH provided by default from the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It is still a good security measure to take though as it is possible for someone to learn the way the requests are made, or a portion of them and try to fake things out. Also it is interesting how this changed on mobile but quite honestly it does not change all that much. Something that is important about the state being checked is that if the user was on a website that was hacked in the WebView then the mobile application could use that state to protect itself from accepting the hacked websites information as true. Anyways this is one of the many conversations that could be had about the state variable.

Hope this helps.
Anthony